# AmazonSQSClient get number of messages in FIFO queue group

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to use the AmazonSQSClient to get the number of messages in an AWS FIFO queue group (messages with a specific MessageGroupId).

I have already looked at some docs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/SQS/TSQSClient.html

The docs hint that I might be able to do what I want with the GetQueueAttributes method... although it isn't clear. I want to do this within a Lambda function.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the only way this would be possible would be to get the messages using `ReceiveMessage` and then count the number of objects in it in code. I don't think you can "inspect" a message group as such. I believe you can only pull 10 at a time as well so there is that to consider.

`GetQueueAttributes` will give you details on the queue not the messages or groups within it.

Comment: I wish among the QueueAttributes it told you the different groups and associated message count within each group. Oh well :(